# Switch from Nmake into MinGW using cygwin

Tags: c++, c, cmake

How to use the MingW instead of the Nmake using cmake ???

I have cygwin installed with Mingw, gcc, g++, and gdb installed on Windows 7 x64

when I try this command :

```
cmake
```

I get a long error containing this:

```
-- Building for: NMake Makefiles
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error: your RC compiler: "CMAKE_RC_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Ple
ase set CMAKE_RC_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
-- Check for CL compiler version
-- Check for CL compiler version - failed
-- Check if this is a free VC compiler
-- Check if this is a free VC compiler - yes
-- Using FREE VC TOOLS, NO DEBUG available
-- Check for working C compiler: cl

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):



CMake Error: your C compiler: "cl" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_C_COMPILER
to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "cl" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPI
LER to a valid compiler path or name.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should choose

> MinGW Makefiles.

If `gcc` is not in path, you should choose

> Specify native compilers

to point paths to compiler binaries.